# special substrings with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all substrings of a given type: **xyx** or **xxyxx** and so on.
For example in string: **abcbaba** possible substrings are: **bcb**, **bab** and **aba**.

My simplest pattern is: `r'([a-z]+)[a-z](\1)'` but it doesn't match substring **bab**.
It looks like this pattern can only see the substings next to each other but not overlapping.
The second problem is that regex also matches substrings of the same letters, and shouldn't :(

I am asking for a hint or some help.
I'm learning regex using python.

Comment: [`[x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(r'(?=(([a-z]+)[a-z]\2))', s)]`](https://ideone.com/k8P3wW)

Comment: Thanks for the hint.